# Efficient algorithm for counting number of pairs of identical elements in an array

Tags: c, arrays, performance, algorithm

For example,

```
int num[] = {1, 5, 3, 12, 5, 1, 4};
int len = 7;
int count = 0;
```

(Assuming there are no more than 2 of identical elements in the array)
Then I would do

```
for(int i=0; i<len-1; i++) {
  for(int j=i+1; j<len; j++) {
    if(num[i] == num[j]) {
      count++;
    }
  }
}
```

Then count would be 2.

But this algorithm results in the efficiency of O(N^2).
Is there a more efficient way?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you can sort the array, the overall time will be O(n log n) - the sort is n log n, and finding identical elements will be linear.

Comment: Are negative values allowed? What is the largest/smallest value of an int in the array?

Answer (score 5):

Faster than an `O(n log n)` sort, use a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Its construction is linear or `O(n)`; every time you insert, as you walk through your input array, you can test (with constant, `O(1)` cost) if there is that key already in your hash table — *i.e.*, a "pair". When you find this "match" case, you increment a counter. Once you have gone through your array, your counter tells you the answer.

Comment: How do you deal with collisions? If you assume n slots in your hash table and a perfect hash, then yes you have O(n). But if you use a fixed size -- k say -- hash table then there will be an average of n/k in each slot, and to insert an element will be O(n/k) = O(n), so O(n*n) just to build the table.

Comment: A hash table large enough (say the size of the initial array) should make collisions quite rare (except with a bad hash function). To handle buckets for elements hashing to the same key, one could use lists or logarithmic access data structures (heaps, balanced trees ...). The latters seem a bit overkill for the exercise but guarantees O(n.ln n) time.

Comment: A hit in the hash table gives just a candidate for a duplicate. You then compare the item in focus with the item from the table to finally judge if they are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way:

```
#define MAX 99999   // consider your array have largest elemnt < 99999 and >=0
    int main () {
    int num[] = {1, 5, 3, 12, 5, 1, 4,3};
    int len = 8;
    int count[MAX+1u] = {0};
    int i,pair=0;
    for( i=0;i<len;i++){
         count[num[i]]++;   // here count the frequecy of each number
    }
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
     if(count[i]>1){               // if frequecy is > 1      
    printf("%d occurs %d times \n",i,count[i]);
    pair++;         // increment pair
    }

    }
    printf("%d pairs ",pair);   // print pair
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @chux i were updating that time. yes sure.

Comment: The memory usage would be quite huge with this solution. This is the best of course if you know you are getting integers from a "little" interval.

Comment: You should edit your answer with a little "disclaimer". The hash table solution becomes better (regarding memory usage) when the input data set grows too much. Also your implementation assume there is no negative integer in the array.

Comment: @Rerito what about collision. suppose you have few data then how you gonna get unique hashkey.

Comment: Using buckets, implemented using a proper data structure would grant you a O(n.ln n) time. Of course, most cases would be pretty close to linear time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64384/discussion-between-rustam-and-rerito).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the core idea remains the same : you have to count the number of occurences of each element in your input array.

The key problem is how to implement this counting process. Your solution is perfectly valid, but as you felt it, it can be improved.
You received a comment suggesting sorting the array and then perform a sweep on it to count the number of pairs : O(n.ln n).

You could also use a hash table, as suggested by @AlexReynolds answer. But you must deal with collisions, as different integers could hash to the same key. To do so, you could use a bucket for each key. This bucket would store every integer that hashed to its key, plus the number of occurences of the said integer.

How to implement these buckets :

- With *Lists* ? If you have a few collisions, this is good enough.
- With *Heaps* (like binary heap) : logarithmic access and insertion, but fixed size and you might need reallocation if too much collisions occur. This is good if you don't underestimate the number of collisions but increases memory usage if you overestimate it.
- With *Balanced Binary Trees* : logarithmic lookup and insertion, but spatial overhead due to the pointer tracking going on "inside". But here, you avoid the estimation problem *heaps* induced.

Once your hashtable is built, with the occurences of each element present in your array, you must count the pairs. But you could keep a counter **while populating the data structure** to avoid performing this extra sweep. This is easy. Here are the basic operations used to update the table with an element *e* taken from the array :

1. Hash *e* : we get a Hash key *k*
2. Get the bucket of the hash key *k* : *b*
3. Look up the bucket to see if *e* is in there :

   - If so : increment the element occurrence counter. **If the counter is 2, increment the pair counter, if the counter is 3, decrement the pair counter.**
   - If not : add the element to the bucket, with an occurrence counter set to 1
4. Get the next element in the input array in *e* and repeat until the array has been fully sweeped.

Is performing one **if** statement at each *counter update* faster than performing a simple check in the end ? I am not sure, just be aware you can test both.

Let *k* be the number of slots in the hash table. With a uniformly distributed hash function, you would get *n/k* elements per slot. This leads to a n²/k time complexity with lists, which is O(n²) ... **But** if *k* is close to *n* you get really close to a linear time.

The same goes for heap/tree buckets, except that in the end you get a O(n. ln n) asymptotic complexity. If k is large enough, again, you will be close to linear time.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use a normal hash table. I used dynamic programming and a hashtable.

You should set up your hash-table like this:

[value of array, Number of repetition, number of identical pair]

For example, we can run my algorithm on the array `A = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]`.

we walk through Array. for first number in A, the new row is inserted to the hashtable

```
  3,0,0 /* A[i], the number of repetition of 3 so far (Rep[i]),
                    the number of identical pair so far ( Iden[i]). */
```

then for second 3 in A:

```
 3,1,1
```

for third 3 in A:

```
 3,2,3
```

for 4th 3 in A:

```
 3,3,6
```

6 is the number of identical pairs in this array. In general, we can calculate the number of identical pair by following formula:

**Iden[i] = Rep[i] + Iden[i-1]**

Here's a code sample in C#:

```
     public static int solution(int[] A)
    {
         int identical = 0;
        Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<int, int>> dic = new Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<int, int>>(); /* A[i], the number of repetition of 3 so far (Rep[i]),
                    the number of identical pair so far ( Iden[i]). */
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!dic.ContainsKey(A[i]))
                dic.Add(A[i], new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0,0));
            else
            { 
               KeyValuePair<int,int> valDic = dic[A[i]];

                KeyValuePair<int, int> newVal;
                if (valDic.Key < 1)
                    newVal = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 1);
                else
                {
                    int preIdenticalPair = valDic.Value;
                    int preReptation = valDic.Key;
                    int newRepetation = ++preReptation;
                    int newIdenticalPair = preIdenticalPair + newRepetation;
                    newVal = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(newRepetation, newIdenticalPair);
                }

                dic[A[i]] = newVal;
            }
        }

        //summation of all identical pairs
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, KeyValuePair<int, int>> pair in dic)
            identical += pair.Value.Value;
        return identical;
    }
```

Comment: The question is tagged [c]